# Is it possible to prove that applied forces to a bicycle top tube are worse than a seatpost when using a repair stand clamp?

Tags: bicycles, carbon-fiber

This stems from the idea that you should use a bike stand clamp on a seatpost, if you can, for carbon fiber (CF) bike frames. Hopefully, this would avoid the cracking of a CF bike frame.

In order to prove that it's safer to clamp on a seatpost vs. a CF bike frame top tube, can we mathematically prove the acting forces on a top tube vs. seatpost is safer than the other?

Comment: What is the seat post made of? What size is the clamp? Is the frame designed with thicker points especially for clamping? So much detail missing.

Comment: Can we?  Probably, given the forces involved and the geometry of the forces.  My opinion is these things are best left to mechanics who do the work regularly.

Comment: When you consider the seatpost tube is actually meant to be clamped (unlike frame tubes in general), the bike stand clamp makes more sense. Also seatpost is designed to transfer your weight onto the frame, whereas typical loading of top frame tube is different (unless you take another passenger sitting on it).